# Duplicate Content on Category Pages in different location eCommerce

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, local-seo

I have an issue with possible duplicate content.

So, I have e-commerce and its parent URL is example.com. It's followed by regional URL ( Cities)

- `example.com/city-1`
- `example.com/city-2`
- `example.com/city-3`

Now, the issue is that we have created the content for the main page and in which we are using the term

```
Title in {Location}
```

And in the content we are using again `{location}` 
Where `{Location}` is automatically replaced by city-1, city-2 & city-3

Is it good or bad for SEO? Also, what is a good alternative creating separate content for each city category pages because the same category exists in all the 3 cities as well as in the parent URL

Comment: Are other pages on your site more customized between the different city sections?

Comment: No, they are like the exact replica only the difference is the type of products which are listed is different.
Rest, the design, architecture everything is same

Answer (score -1):

You can use canonical tag to handle these product pages duplicate content, also read this guide for better optimization of these page https://neilpatel.com/blog/product-page-duplicate-content/